# opencv imshow is not responding

Tags: python, opencv, input

Objective of the code:

I'm using opencv and pytesseract to OCR some image. Due to the fact I can't control image quality and definition, I need to detect incomplete OCR and do the job myself. So I try to show the image using cv2.imshow() followed by an input() query.

Problem:

The imshow windows is opening but not responding, showing only grey. Code get back to work if I complete any input.

```
            cv2.imwrite("count.png", count_zone)
            zone = cv2.imread("count.png")

            # read numbers with pytesseract


            gray = cv2.cvtColor(zone, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            _, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

            ocr = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(config.zone_root))
            value = ''.join(re.findall('[0-9]+', ocr))

            #todo: find a way to close the image once the query is entered

            if value == "":
                
                cv2.imshow("Value", zone)
                print("ENTRE THE VALUE:")
                value = input()

                cv2.destroyWindow("Value")
```

Tested solution:

1. If I use Pillow, I can read the image but closing it is a problem
2. I tried to put imshow in line 3, same issue
3. If I put input in comment, the code works perfectly

Comment: Where's [waitKey()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7)? Also, `input()` is blocking the entire Python process.

Comment: I tried to put waitkey or timesleep, did worked

Answer (score 0):

If using ***Spyder***:

Open 'Tools' then '***Prefences***' in the toolbar.

In the window that opens, click the '***IPython console***' setting from the menu on the left.

Click the '***Graphics***' tab in the newly opened window.
Set '***Backend***' to '***Automatic***' and press '***Apply***' then '***Ok***'.

You can find the solution by doing '***Restart***' in the '***File***' menu in the Spyder toolbar.